# How to fix Memory Error while using PIL in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-imaging-library

I'm creating a bot to automate the label making process. i encountered this problem while trying to save (append) multiple images to a pdf. This issue only happens when I'm using a large no. of images and the program works fine if I'm using a few image.

I want to fix this program so that it can process unlimited no. of images and append it to a single pdf file.

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import textwrap
import pandas
import datetime
import numpy
import os
from tkinter import filedialog
from tqdm import tqdm_gui
datenow = datetime.datetime.now()
pdate = datenow.strftime("%d-%m-%y")
y = 0
excel = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/", title="Select A File", filetypes=(("Excel File", "*.xlsx"),("all files", "*.*")))
save_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()
imlist = []
df = pandas.read_excel(excel)
for data in (df.values):
    name, no = data
    x = 0
    while x<no:
        x = x+1
        y = y+1
        LH = len(name)
        if LH < 32:
            W = 70
            Lng = 16
        if LH > 32:
            W = 53
            Lng = 22

        name = name.upper()
        para = textwrap.wrap(name, width=Lng)
        MAX_W, MAX_H = 800, 592
        im = Image.open('TFC.jpg')
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        font = ImageFont.truetype('OpenSans-ExtraBold.ttf', W)
        current_h, pad = 155, -5
        for line in para:
            w, h = draw.textsize(line, font=font)
            draw.text(((MAX_W - w) / 2, current_h), line, font=font)
            current_h += h + pad
        imlist.append(im)



im.save(f'{save_dir}/{pdate}{" TF "}{y}.pdf' , save_all=True, append_images=imlist)
os.startfile(save_dir)
```

The error which I'm getting:

```
"C:\Users\RAJA MONSINGH\PycharmProjects\Fuzzy\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/RAJA MONSINGH/PycharmProjects/Lable/lable3.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\RAJA MONSINGH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 465, in Draw
    return im.getdraw(mode)
AttributeError: 'JpegImageFile' object has no attribute 'getdraw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/RAJA MONSINGH/PycharmProjects/Lable/lable3.py", line 34, in <module>
    draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
  File "C:\Users\RAJA MONSINGH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 467, in Draw
    return ImageDraw(im, mode)
  File "C:\Users\RAJA MONSINGH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\ImageDraw.py", line 59, in __init__
    im.load()
  File "C:\Users\RAJA MONSINGH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 233, in load
    s = read(self.decodermaxblock)
  File "C:\Users\RAJA MONSINGH\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\PIL\JpegImagePlugin.py", line 394, in load_read
    s = self.fp.read(read_bytes)
MemoryError

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Files needed to run the program:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rS-auW0MHmdjoPlNET71isL8AyEPPyGT/view?usp=sharing

Comment: you could read image only once - before loop - and later only duplicate it `im.copy()`. You could also load all fonts only once - before loop - and later select fonts without loading it again.

Comment: Your question isn't really the *"Minimum Complete Verifiable Example"* required by StackOverflow. Try and make it more focussed on the actual issue rather than including code for `Tkinter`, `Pandas`, `Excel`. You are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: if you have problem with memory then maybe first create all files on disk - without keeping im memory - and later run other script or other program which can convert it to `PDF`. I usually use [imagemagic](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) instead of `Python` to convert images. It can also convert serie of images to `PDF` - ie. `convert *.jpg output.pdf`